How to Timestamp and Lock Cell with VBA Object when Adjacent Cell equals "a"
I have a checklist with a row for each task.  I would like for a cell in the same row as a task, to record a timestamp when the viewer double-clicks an adjacent cell.  This would show the date in which the task was completed or checked-off.
The user can double-click the box-cell to rotate through an entry of "a" = accepted, "r" = rejected, or "p" = pending.
When it's "a" accepted, I would like for a time stamp to appear in Column E of the same row.
Column C = "a", "r", or "p" and the target time stamp is Column E of the same row, n.
I don't receive any errors with the following but nothing appears in Cell (E,n)
The Date format should be MM/DD/YY
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Target, Range("Selection")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value < "a" Then
        Target.Value = "a" 'Sets target Value = "a"
        n = Target.Row
        If Excel.Range("E" & n).Value <> "" Then
        Excel.Range("E" & n).Value = Now
        End If
        Cancel = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Target.Value = "a" Then
        Target.Value = "r"
        Cancel = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Target.Value = "r" Then
        Target.Value = "p"
        Cancel = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Target.Value = "p" Then
        Target.Value = "a"
        Cancel = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
    End Sub


The first thing I notice is If Target.Value < "a" Then - you are using "less than" on a String, and that's not going to work.

braX - it will cycle through a, r, and then p, so that part works but it will not time stamp on "a"

Should it timestamp only on the first "a", or also on every p > a transition?

This If Excel.Range("E" & n).Value <> "" always returns false because that cell is empty. Also, you can improve your code by 1: Using select case instead of several IFs; 2: Compare either cell. Value with Empty or cell. Text with ""; 3: excel. Cells(n,"E").value=now .

Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    With Target
        If .Column = 3 And .Row > 1 Then
            If Len(.Value) = 0 Then ' if status is blank, populated "a"
                .Value = "a"
            Else
                ' populate next status
                Dim aStatus, vVal: aStatus = Split("a r p a")
                vVal = Application.Match(.Value, aStatus, 0)
                If Not IsError(vVal) Then
                    .Value = aStatus(vVal)
                End If
            End If
            If .Value = "a" Then ' populated timestamp
                .Offset(, 2).Value = Date
                .Offset(, 2).NumberFormat = "MMM/dd/yy"
            Else ' clear timestamp if status = "r" or "p"
'                .Offset(, 2).Value = ""
            End If
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub


